# Display Custom Taxonomy Field in sidebar

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, taxonomy

Hi Guys, I'm trying to display a *taxonomy field* called `clpr_store_video` in my Wordpress sidebar for each store is it possible to call the field value outside the loop on the sidebar, but yet attached to the post id?

I don't really know if its possible or how to do that.

**EDITED**

What I've tried from another tutorial but no luck.

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
$subheading = get_field('clpr_store_video', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);
echo $subheading;
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your code

Comment: Hi @Mark, i've added the code that i've found in another blog, but its not working, i'm not sure if that's the code i have to use

Comment: Sorry @WilliamXavier still more info needed.. You mention stores, are you using WooCommerce plugin? Also what is clpr_store_video?

Answer (score 0):

See code block to display taxonomy associated with post and list of taxonomies and their links:

If you wish to get taxonomy associated with particular post

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'clpr_store_video' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

  echo $subheading = $term->name;

}
```

If you wish to get list and link of all taxonomies

```
<ul>
<?php  

$taxonomies = get_terms('clpr_store_video', array("fields" => "all"));

foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy) {

  echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $taxonomy ).'">'.$taxonomy->name.'</a></li>';

} 
?>
</ul>
```